# How to avoid duplicate processing when activity is relaunched with the same intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Our activity can be launched from a GCM notification.  We set extras in the GCM intent to ensure the user is taken to the message thread for that GCM notification, and we call `removeExtra` afterwards to remove it from the intent.

If the user launches our app from the recent history menu, then the activity is started with the same intent as from the previous launch (e.g. from the GCM notification).

This scenario is quite easy to detect:

```
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // If the caller intent is from the recent apps and has the RECIPIENT_ID_KEY
    // extra we should remove it to avoid open the messages thread again
    if (((i.getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) != 0) &&
             i.hasExtra(MyConstants.RECIPIENT_ID_KEY)) {
        i.removeExtra(MyConstants.RECIPIENT_ID_KEY);
    }
```

However, we also want this to work if the activity has been destroyed by the OS.  At the moment, when the Developer option "Do not keep activities" is set (only available on OS 4.0+), then the activity keeps being recreated with the same intent when pressing the Back button from another one of our screens, resulting in bad things happening.

I considered adding a unique extra in our GCM intent and saving that in Shared Preferences once we have processed it.  However, we also need this to work when sharing an image into our app through a `SEND image/jpg` intent.  We don't control that intent, so how will we know if we've already processed it?  I guess we could use the file/URI information, although that means if a user shares the same image twice in a row, we'll ignore the second one.

Is there a clean and simple way to solve this problem?

We currently support OS 2.3+, and our application is available all around the world.  Here's the relevant section of my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.MyClass"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
```

Comment: I think adding an extra from GCM intent and then putting a check in the Activity.onNewIntent() for the existance of this extra would be more than enough

Comment: onNewIntent() will not be called if the user launches the app from the Recent History menu after the activity was destroyed (but the previous intent information is still provided again).

Comment: Hmm...i guess that was the reason I sometimes call onNewIntent() from onCreate().  Maybe the different scenarios you describe could benefit from when onNewIntent() is called or not?

Answer (score 0):

I was interested in how to solve the part:

> However, we also need this to work when sharing an image into our app
>   through a SEND image/jpg intent.

As soon as I handle the images I put an extra flag on the Intent. As you can imagine, I check for that flag before doing the files processing. This worked even if the Intent was created by another application.